# Mongoose find By condition otherwise find all ($or)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

if you pass **categoryId** it will return category with that **categoryId** but if you don't pass
it, I want this route ***to return all categories***...
I tried this with $or but it always returns all categories regardless of I passed **categoryId** or not :

```
await Category.find({ $or: [{ _id: categoryId }, {}] });
```

I can use the if statement but it takes a lot of code, can this be done cleaner?

Comment: just create empty object then use if condition and check if  `categoryId` is present, if yes then add `_id` key in the object and use that object as where condition in `find`

Comment: seems good too, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
await Category.find({ _id: (categoryId || {$exists: true}) });
```